# Why $X_n\rightarrow X$ a.e. is NOT enough in convergence

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider a probability space $(\Omega,F,P).$

In monotone convergence theorem and dominated convergence theorem, $X_n\rightarrow X$ a.e. is NOT enough to warrant the interchange of the limit and integral. We need conditions such as boundedness or non-decreasing sequence of measurable functions.

I just have done an exercise doing this on $\Omega=[0,1],F=B([0,1]),P=Lebesgue$. Consider

$$X_n(\omega) =\begin{cases}
n & \text{if } \omega \in (0,\frac{1}{n}) \\
   0       & \text{if } \omega \in (\frac{1}{n},1] \text{ or } \omega=0.
  \end{cases}$$

I basically shown that the DCT fails, but I am having a hard time gaining intuition what's going on in here that makes DCT fails.

Can someone provide pedagogical response with intuition and insight generally both with the above example and that why almost everywhere or point-wise convergence is not enough?

Comment: The integral accounts for products of values multiplied by the size of the sets in which the function returns that value. Convergence a.e. (to $0$, which is the only important case) tells that the sizes of those sets, for a given positive value, tend to zero. That is only one of the two factors involved in the multiplications appearing in the integral. In your example, they exploit this by making the values that the functions take large enough such that when you multiply the product doesn't get small.

Comment: $X_n$'s are not dominated by an integrable random variable.